# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' tras usar innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, buscador

presento el siguiente problema: estoy tratando de hacer un buscador, para esto tengo en html una lista de divs que se encuentran dentro de un div padre de la siguiente forma:

```
    <div class="bb" id="bb">
  </div>
    <div class="b" id="b">

  <div  class="v1" id="v1">
    <div id="b5" value="<table><tr>
    <td>Celda 1</td> 
    <td>Celda 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Celda 3</td>
    <td>Celda 4</td>
  </tr>
  </table>"  class="b5"  onclick="clicke(event)" >
      <div class="bb1">nombre del producto1<br><br> especificacion </div>
      <div class="bb2" name="gomas">gg</div>
  </div>

    <div  id="b4" class="b2"  onclick="clicke(event)" value="<table ><tr>
    <td>Celda 5</td> 
    <td>Celda 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Celda 7</td>
    <td>Celda 8</td>
  </tr>
  </table>">
      <div class="bb1">nombre del producto2<br><br> especificacion </div>
      <div class="bb2" name="gomas">gg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para tomar el elemento deseado hago algo sencillo, capturo con una entrada de texto el elemento deseado y luego compruebo cuantos elementos llamados así hay, oculto la lista que tenia inicialmente con divs (b) y creo aparezco una oculta (bb), ya obtenido el numero de elementos que deseo, creo un contador con for, en el cual uno a uno los elementos llamados de la misma forma se hacen hijos de la lista "bb", y aquí aparece el problema, pues al realizar otra busqueda deseo limpiar este div de los elementos hijos para colocar otros nuevos, pero al utilizar *bb.innerHTML=""* o *bb.removeChild(texto2)*  *Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.* Aqui el codigo javascript

```
bb.style.display="none";

function buscar(){
//buscador de texto
  
  let texto=document.getElementById("texto1").value;
let ide=document.getElementsByClassName(texto).length;
b.style.display="none";
 bb.style.display="block";
 
  bb.innerHTML="";
  
  let texto2="";
i2=i2+1;
  for(let num=0; num<ide; num++){
 texto2 = document.getElementsByClassName(texto)[num];

   bb.appendChild(texto2);
      }
  
}
```

Ya he intentado de muchas formas, de hecho ya he utilizado estos metodos antes con currenttarget y no me habia generado problema, alguna idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es descrito en la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> Si el hijo(Child) es una referencia(hace referencia) hacia un nodo existente en el documento actual, **este es quitado del padre actual para ser puesto en el nodo padre nuevo**. La clave está en si el (Child) es una referencia a un nodo existente en el documento.

Entonces, debes [clonar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) e insertar el nuevo nodo.

**Importante:**

1. No uses `document` para obtener los elementos a copiar, usa como fuente el contenedor donde se encuentran. De lo contrario, estarás trabajando sobre todos elementos que aparezcan en el documento.
2. No es necesario crear una variable para contar la cantidad de elementos obtenidos, es mejor obtener los elementos y usar la propiedad `.length` para limitar el `for`.
3. Dentro del ciclo accedes al elemento por índice, lo clonas y agregas la copia al contenedor correspondiente.

```
function buscar(){
    //buscador de texto
    let texto=document.getElementById("texto1").value;
    // Obtener solo elementos en contenedor original
    let texto2=b.getElementsByClassName(texto);

    b.style.display="none";
    bb.style.display="block";
    // Limpia el contenedor, no hay problema
    bb.innerHTML="";

    // Limitas el for con la cantidad de elementos obtenidos
    for(let num=0; num<texto2.length; num++){
        // Inserta una copia, en lugar del original
        bb.appendChild(texto2[num].cloneNode(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la inmediatez de tu respuesta triby. Con respecto a esta solución, ya la había imaginado pero no me funciona debido a que al darle buscar nuevamente, los productos anteriores no se borran, la verdad no se porque sucede, es como si no funcionase el *bb.innerHtml=“”*

Comment: @Adrián21, revisa la actualización de la respuesta